# Access to the port "COM1" is denied

Tags: c#, port

I have a RFID devices connected to my laptop through Port COM1(Confirmed correct whereby i had using device manager). However, when i run these code in C# language. It give me an exception **Access to the port "COM1" is denied**. Anyone can help me to solve this problem? Below is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace Testing1
{
    public class Testing1
    {
        public static SerialPort iSerialPort = new SerialPort();

        static int Main() 
        {
            string strException = string.Empty;
            string strComPort = "COM1";
            int nBaudrate=Convert.ToInt32(9600);

            int nRet = OpenCom(strComPort, nBaudrate, out strException);
            if (nRet != 0)
            {
                string strLog = "Connect reader failed, due to: " + strException; 
                Console.WriteLine(strLog);
                //return;
            }
            else
            {
                string strLog = "Reader connected " + strComPort + "@" + nBaudrate.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(strLog);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();

            iSerialPort.Close();
            return 0;
        }

        public static int OpenCom(string strPort, int nBaudrate, out string strException)
        {

            strException = string.Empty;

            if (iSerialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                iSerialPort.Close();
            }

            try
            {
                iSerialPort.PortName = strPort;
                iSerialPort.BaudRate = nBaudrate;
                iSerialPort.ReadTimeout = 200;
                iSerialPort.DataBits = 8;
                iSerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
                iSerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                iSerialPort.Open();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                strException = ex.Message;
                return -1;
            }



            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This exception can occur when some other program is accessing the COM1 port. Do you have any other program open that uses the RFID device?

You can check what programs use what ports using [Portmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx).

Comment: If there is other program accessing COM1 port, can i change the port number that my RFID device is using to solve the number. Like changing from COM1 to COM2 in device manager?

Comment: That depends on the program that is using it. If it autodetects the COM ports and uses the port that your reader is connected to, changing the port number won't help you. Of course, you can try and see if it will work or not. You can also close the program or disable its startup, maybe that will help.

Comment: Do you any other scenario that might cause the exception to occur? I am trying the solution but it does not seem to help. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks i change the port to a definitely not in used port which is COM17. It works actually. thanks a lot, it tooks me a while to figure out how to change though