# c# com port unhandled exception?

Tags: c#, serial-port

In VS2019 community on Win10/64 I have a Com port with which my c# program exchanges serial data.
The same port can be opened by another application on the same computer.

When the port is opened by the other app and I try to access the port from my current app, I (expectedly) receive an exception message.

**The exception message is of type:** `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException`: 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

and **the inner exception is:** `UnauthorizedAccessException`: Access to the port 'COM6' is denied.

So far so good.

The problem is that I can not handle that (or any other relevant) exception. With any exception catch I still get the message and the program halts to be restarted.
I have tried the general exception handler and all relevant (as is indicated by the documentation) exceptions and placed a break in each handler, for no avail. The program still halts at the same exception message.

**This is what I have tried (each with a break):**

`catch (Exception ex)`

`catch (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException portInUse)`

`catch (UnauthorizedAccessException portInUse)`

`catch (InvalidOperationException portInUse)`

`catch (FormatException)`

`catch (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException)`

**This is the full call stack message:**

> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
> System.IO.Ports.InternalResources.WinIOError(int, string)
> System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.SerialStream(string, int, System.IO.Ports.Parity, int,
> System.IO.Ports.StopBits, int, int, System.IO.Ports.Handshake, bool, bool, bool, byte)
> System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Open()
> Lift_Motor_Control.Main.btnSend_Click(object, System.EventArgs) in Main.cs
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

Comment: Can you show the relevant section of your code with the exception handling you've added.

Comment: For example, these may be the case. [why is access to com port denied?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7220569/9014308), [Access to the port 'COM5' is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12657479/9014308), [Access to the port "COM1" is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23672344/9014308), [Serial Port UnauthorizedAccessException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/343511/serial-port-unauthorizedaccessexception.html)